# Is google maps api the right tool for the job? For something like wikimapia

Tags: google-maps

This is how last part of my application(php/mysql website) is supposed to work:

BackEnd for the  Admin : a standard zoomable (google?) map of a city on which polygons(or circles) representing colonies can be drawn using a pen tool .(like wikimapia)

Database: the location and shape of the drawn city block is stored.

UI for the user: the user can see the  standard zoomable google map  along with the drawn colonies in his browser. He can then select a colony, enter a radius and gets a list of all colonies lying within the circle.

Is google maps api and javascript right tools for the job ? If so how difficult does this sound ? if not , then what else? pure javascript combined with static google maps api ?

Any other suggestions ?

I am a beginner-intermediate php programmer at best, know a little of a few languages (C#).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't it? Yes, I think google maps is right tool for the job. I've seen similar things done in google maps API:

- http://www.wikiloc.org/ (drawing polylines)
- http://telmee.nl/ (drawing polygons and polylines)